# WordPress - Contact Form7 - Modify php code of analyze to inject own spam-check

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have Breaked my lance searching over english and russian manuals

Info:
I`m running site on the Wordpress platform.
Its contact form is WordpressContactForm7.

The Issue:
spam is beeing REPEATEDLY sent 5-7 times a day 
through the contact form to my callcenter`s email.

My work:
I made simple spam filter in php that block common phrases and emails,
that beeing found in body of message - makes its spam-rating hotter and hotter.

Everything after spam-level 90% is blocked.
Everything after 60%  must block user to 1-email-a-day- mode

The Problem :
I could not find any proper place in WPCF7 phpcode to inject my own.

I am new to wordpress and could find only two entry-points:
1) virtual address of data-processor
sitename.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/46550/feedback
that is virtual and tells me nothing about the place where wpcf7 have server-processing and sending to my mail.

2) installation ZIP of contact-form-7 plugin
Also it has lots of everything - 
And I watched through carefully - but I found I cannot make a full image of it in my mind /

So I decided to ask for the help the experienced coder to show off the different ways to deal with that.

P.S.
(Note1 I am a little affraid of WP, and prefer to rely on my own raw php skills and build-from-zero code constructions. I`m much better dealing the code done by me rather than somebody outer`s.)

(Note2 I ve heard that json api is vuln...)

(Note3 I`m afraid of updating any components - the cause is that WP is controlled and carried by superirors - so any my fault can be the last one^)

Please Kindly consult me on the topic, If possible <3
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CF7 have a lot of hooks and filters actually, like `wpcf7_skip_mail`,`wpcf7_mail_sent`,`wpcf7_before_send_mail` and others..

e,g:

```
 add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_my_before_send_mail' );

   function wpcf7_my_before_send_mail( $wpcf7 ) {

       // put your logic  code here

   }
```

the following is special for skipping mail

```
 add_filter( 'wpcf7_skip_mail', function( $skip_mail, $contact_form ) {

       if( /* your logic */ )

           $skip_mail = true;

       return $skip_mail;

   }, 10, 2 );
```

combining this logic, you can also do something like

```
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_do_something");  
function wpcf7_do_something($cf7) {
    // this is the contact form object
    $wpcf = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();

    // exam0ple : ID of Form $wpcf->id

    if (/*your logic here*/) {
        // If you want to skip mailing... 
        $wpcf->skip_mail = true;    
    }

    return $wpcf;
}
```

you should also look at the [CF7 Docs](https://contactform7.com/docs/), you could find some other ways of fighting spam like [ip_blacklist](https://contactform7.com/comment-blacklist/) and other tips

Comment: Thank You Great, Wonder! – This is good enaugh to understand the basics of  technology,  open eyes and start codding)))

So I used a word "hook" got from you - and found a thing that  I could`nt find at the official contactform7 site.
So = [hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7](http://hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7/4.7/hooks/#index=a)

All other things I will keep in my mind. Thank You

Comment: while the hookr site is a known site for listing wp related hooks, the documentation and example themselves are auto-generated and usually without explanation, this is why I sent you to the official docs.. Anyhow glad you find it yourself.- after all this is exactly how wp works on core level, and also plugin and themes. hooks and filters.

Comment: still failed to find a hooks data & examples at https://contactform7.com/docs/\

:(

Everything there - all three  blocks of topics - seems to be javascript or admin-panel nested.

Cannot find anything related to the hooks in the headlines  at the CF7 Docs page

Comment: Could you tell me,  how can I get a data from input fields..
Which hook or whick property of objects should I use to do this.
Could you type that code line please..

Comment: you have it in the last code example. `$wpcf = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();`